# Binding elements to values in WPF

Tags: c#, data-binding

I'm trying to bind a Textbox to a string defined in the .cs file using the followings:

Xaml Code:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox_Data" CaretBrush="DodgerBlue" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding Data}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="123" SelectionChanged="textBox_Data_SelectionChanged"/>
```

Xaml.cs Code:

```
public string Data{get; set;}
```

But the string isn't updating...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class has to derive from `INotifyPropertyChanged` and you have to implement it in your property setter

Or more pleasant way: Install `PropertyChanged.Fody` from nuget. You can read more about it here: https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged

And keep in mind, not to use `this.DataContext=this;` when initializing your window, use binding as **dovid** suggests.

Answer (score 0):

`{Binding Data}` refer the `DataContext` of current element (or to one of ancestors).

**one way**

for refer the xaml.xxx.cs you need refer the Window element, you can give him a name:

```
<Window x:Name="window" x:Class=...
```

and change the Binding to refer element name:

```
Text="{Binding Data, ElementName=window}"
```

**Second way**

you can also inject all window class to current DataContext:

```
<Window DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" x:Class=...
```

Now you can leave the original expression:

```
Text="{Binding Data}"
```

**Third way**

You can also set DataContext from the code. do not change anything in xaml, and add in this line (`DataContext = this;`) at end of constructor:

```
 public xyz() {

     InitializeComponent();
     //...
     DataContext = this;
 }
```

Comment: Do not use ``DataContext = this;``, it is bad practice and a trap for beginners.